# REGEX-Match characters present in a string

Tags: regex, string

What is the REGEX to accept a string like this

- Starts with EDO
- has many characters(words,numbers,hypehns) in between
- does not contain 24 or |(pipe)

Example:
Should match

```
edo-<<characters>>-<<characeters>>-<<numbers>>
```

BUT NOT

```
edo-<<characters>>-<<characeters>>-<<numbers>> | <<characeters>>- <<characeters>>- <<numbers>>
```

The string does not have a constant length

Comment: *does not contain 24* is quite vague. what if `-24-` and `-124-` which must be accpeted?

Answer (score 1):

The [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will help you to decide if the string doesnt contain `24` or `|`

The regex can be written as

```
/^edo(?!.*(24|\|))[-a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eK3eC3/1)

**How it matches**

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `edo` The anchor ensures that the string starts with `edo`
- `(?!.*(24|\|))` look ahead assertion. It checks if the string doesnt contain `24` or `|`. If it doesnt contain, then proceeds with the remaining pattern. If it contains, discards the match
- `[-a-zA-Z0-9]+` Matches numbers alphabets or `-`
- `$` anchors the regex at the end of the string.

Comment: This will not match lines with `124` as well

Answer (score 0):

```
^EDO(?!.*(?:(?<!\d)24(?!\d)|\|))[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+$
```

Try this.This should work.Use flag `gmi`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/37

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  EDO                      'EDO'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                         (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  24                       '24'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9-]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                       '0' to '9', '-' (1 or more times (matching
                       the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                       string
```

Comment: the modifier should be "gmi" otherwise it will only match EDO not edo. You can try this: https://regex101.com/r/wJ0hE0/1

Comment: `has many characters(words,numbers,hypehns) in between`, i don't know where the space comes from.

Comment: @AvinashRaj by words i guess it gets implied automatically.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yeah newaz its a small change